# Can't import the 'Serial' library to connect with Arduino

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to connect a blender project to Arduino but I have a problem with blender. I cannot import or use the 'serial' library. I can control an LED with Python and Arduino, but when I try it with blender it doesnt work.

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: You probably need this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5390/installing-pyserial-in-blender

Comment: you typed `impor` instead of `import`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found my problem (windows):

I was using and installing 32bits python and 64 bits from blender.

**My solution:**

1. I'm using Windows 10 64 bits.
2. Download Blender 32 bits,v2.79.
3. Remove/uninstall all Python stuff that i have.
4. Reboot the system.
5. Reinstall Python 3.5.3 (64-bits) donwloaded from Python site.
6. Download the pyserial, version 3.4.
7. Copy from pyserial: the folder serial, paste the folder in blender sub-folder site-packages: 
    **/blender-2.79b-windows32/2.79/python/lib/site-packages**
8. Open and run Blender 32 bits,v2.79.
9. Using Blender game engine, made a script and my LED in Arduino turned on.